# Correct selector for toggle button

Tags: html, css, ghost-blog

I cannot grab the correct selector for the toggle button (the toggle button works), but I am aim to show only the first `5` results and when user clicks toggle button (open/close) then the remainer `20` shows. 
I cannot replicate a working example here because the items are dynamically generated and it involves `ejs` code. Question is which is the correct selector for my `css` since shown `css code` does not work.

```css
.module ul li a:nth-child(n+6) {
    display: none!important;
}
```

```html
<section class='module'>
    <div class='header'>Hello</div>
    <div class='content'>
        <% if (site.categories.length){var limit=0;  %>
            <ul class="list">
                <!--<% "EJS code here" %>-->
                    <li>
                        <a class="flat-box" href="<%= url_for(item.path) %>">
                            <div class='name'>
                                <!--<%= item.name %>-->
                            </div>
                            <div class='count'>
                               <!--<%= item.posts.length %>-->
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The toggle button is the hyperlink?

Comment: @ManojKumar - No, the toggle button is defined in my javascript file.

Comment: does the ejs code generate multiple list tags? or does it generate multiple <a></a> tags within the same list?

Comment: In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: With your current CSS, you are targeting the hyperlinks. Please show the element that has the toggle button class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to the 6th `<a></a>` tag inside the `<li></li>`, which it does not exits.

You wish to select the 6th `<li></li>` element.

Your CSS should look like this:

```
.module ul li:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none!important;
}
```